# How can I align views justify in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to align two buttons left and right and I'm using `layout_weight` property width `.25` for both of buttons. But when I did it, buttons width are became %50.

This is what I want:
[image]

This is what I have:
[image]

And this is my XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:textColor="#212121"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/like" />

    <Button
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/button_primary"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try adding `Space` view with layout_weight .5 in between

Comment: add that line to LinearLayout tag ----- android:weightSum="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/like"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:textColor="#212121" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun Cheers ! Accept the answer . Check mark as right if it is helpful to you. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default"
        android:src="@drawable/like"
        android:textColor="#212121" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_primary"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

or like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_default"
        android:src="@drawable/like"
        android:textColor="#212121" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_primary"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun You should accept my answer as first i have given and it is working also.

Comment: @UmutÇağdaşCoşkun You have tick mark wrong one check again.